# Put the graph generated by JavaScript in worksheets

Tags: ms-office, office-js

My add-in written in JavaScript API draws a graph, which can be displayed in the task pane of the add-in. I am wondering if it is possible to automatically put the graph in a worksheet (like we could write a value to a cell by JavaScript API, we now want to copy a graph to a sheet by JavaScript API). As a result, the graph can be saved into the workbook, no matter whether the add-in is loaded later.

Does anyone if this is supported in JavaScript API for Excel?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073931/insert-image-programmatically-office-365-excel-add-in/41077565#41077565 for a related question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say graph, you mean an image.

At this point in time we do not support inserting images into Excel, but feel free to log a feature request at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ and we may consider adding it in the future.

-Philip, Software Developer on the Office Extensibility team